# Basic query on gradle task syntax

Tags: groovy, gradle, build.gradle

I am a Java developer and just joined a project which already uses Gradle. In build.gradle file, I have statements like below

```
springBoot {
  backupSource = false
}

checkstyle {
  configProperties = [basedir: projectDir]
}

task bowerInstall(type: Exec, dependsOn: npmInstall) {
  commandLine 'node', 'node_modules/bower/bin/bower', 'install', '-F', '-s'
}

task gulpBuild(type: Exec, dependsOn: [npmInstall, bowerInstall]) {
  commandLine 'node', 'node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp', 'build', '--release', '--silent'
}
```

Here I understand `bowerInstall` and `gulpBuild` are custom tasks as they have the keyword "task" in the beginning. But what about other statements like `springBoot` and `checkstyle`. It doesn't have the "task" prefix, but it looks like task.

Are they called as tasks ? Can you please clarify my doubt ? Also do you think learning groovy syntax mandatory to write the build.gradle file ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29474890/6509

Comment: @vijvij123 Does my answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `bowerInstall` and `gulpBuild` are plain gradle tasks of type `Exec`. The two other blocks you're asking: `springBoot` and `checkstyle` are *extensions*, please have a look a this [link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionAware.html), the piece of code presented there is pretty self-explanatory.